Will the NumPy broadcast array ever be created during a binary operation?
I have two numpy.ndarray instances with different shapes. If I add these two arrays, broadcasting will occur between them:
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([[2,  3,  5],
              [7, 11, 13]])

print(x + y)
# [[ 3  5  8]
#  [ 8 13 16]]

Will the broadcast array ever be created? That is, will the following array be physically created from x before the operation?
[[1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3]]

The problem is less significant with smaller arrays, but with larger arrays, the difference can be considerable. When implicit broadcasting leads to the creation of a new array, a significant amount of memory can be wasted by repeating the same numbers:
x = np.random.rand(10000)
y = np.random.rand(10000, 10000)

print(x + y)

When the broadcast array is actually created with x, the memory wastage becomes very large.
If such broadcasting occurs, is there a way to avoid creating a new array? If not (i.e. a new array is not created), how are binary operations between mismatching shapes implemented?

The array(s) is expanded via the magic of strides.  np.broadcast_arrays and np.broadcast_to let you see the intermediate product, which will be a view.
In [75]: x=np.array([1,2,3]); y = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

In [76]: X=np.broadcast_to(x,y.shape)

In [77]: y.shape, y.strides
Out[77]: ((2, 3), (12, 4))

In [78]: X.shape, X.strides
Out[78]: ((2, 3), (0, 4))

In [79]: X.base
Out[79]: array([1, 2, 3])

So X has the same shape as y, but the leading strides value is 0.  This allows that dimension to be 'repeated' without actually copying.  Note the base.
In [80]: X+y
Out[80]: 
array([[2, 4, 6],
       [5, 7, 9]])

We get the same strides if we add a leading dimension with None/np.newaxis:
In [81]: x.strides
Out[81]: (4,)    
In [82]: x[None,:].strides
Out[82]: (0, 4)


Thank you for your answer. However, regarding the use of None/np.newaxis, why does the leading stride become zero? I think it would be more reasonable to set it to 12 instead.

but there are only 12 bytes in x.  12 would step off the end.  To get to 2nd row of X you go back to the start, not to the end.
